# How make java.lang.reflect.Method.getReturnType return void.class with EasyMock?

Tags: java, reflection, mocking, easymock

I need to test this code with EasyMock:

```
if (void.class.equals(method.getReturnType)){
    //do something
}
```

I want to mock method.getReturnType() returns void.class. What I must write instead of "????" ?

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

Method method = EasyMock.createMock(Method.class);
EasyMock.expect(method.getReturnType()).andReturn(????);
```

I have tried:

```
EasyMock.expect(method.getReturnType()).andReturn(Void.class);
EasyMock.expect(method.getReturnType()).andReturn(Void);
EasyMock.expect(method.getReturnType()).andReturn(Void.TYPE);
EasyMock.expect(method.getReturnType()).andReturn(void.class);
EasyMock.expect(method.getReturnType()).andReturn(void);
```

But get compilation errors.

Any ideas?

**P.S.** If question is not clear ask me.

Comment: "But get compilation errors" is never enough information - *what* errors do you get in each case? I'd expect the `void.class` version to work.

Comment: (As an aside, I probably wouldn't use mocks for this - why not just create an appropriate method for each situation you want to test, and use the *real* `Method` class?)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

```
EasyMock.expect(method.getReturnType()).andReturn((Class) void.class);
```

But there is EasyMock run time errors because java.lang.reflection.Method is final.